# Minima in a region of 2d matrix with its indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, minima

I have a set of 18 MATLAB vectors (raw readings of current values) data that varies with many minimas and maximas put into a 2d matrix of `B` which has a size of 18 by 16348.

I have found the indices and value of global max of each row vector.
Stored in another vector namely `M` ( has max values of each row vector of `B`) and l (has indices of max of each row vector of `B`). using the below code.

```
[M,l]=max(B,[],2)
```

Now i want to find the minima of each row vector that occurs before this global maxima.

I wrote a loop to look backwards, starting from global max and check for the least value and its indices. The condition for the minima can be imagined as 
b[i,l] < b[i,l-1] & b[i,l] < b[i,l+1]

This put in a loop is as below.

```
o=l;    % l vector has the indices of global max of all 18 vectors%
for i=1:18
    while ( B(i,o(i)) > B(i,o(i)-1)) % to locate the minima before globalmax
            o(i)=o(i)-1;
    end;
            if( B(i,o(i) < B(i, o(i)+1))
            display(o(i));
            display(B(i,o(i)));
            break;
            end;
 end;
```

For some reason the `while` loop executes only once and then stops. That is the problem I am facing.

The plot below is showing 4 of the 18 values plotted and the maxima and minima for a vector marked.

[image: Plot of values, maxima, minima]

Comment: Some sample data and expected result would be good...

Comment: Consider a 2*2 like :
B = [-2 4 18 24 14 19 48 2 3 , -1 5 22 4 56 3 4 2 1]
now what i need is the difference between max and min before that 
i.e in above case i expect difference between 48-14 = 34 and its indices which is B(1,5).
The same way for other vector too. @kkuilla

Comment: @vittalrao - Why would the "minimum" be 14 in the above case when looking backwards at 48 when it's the maximum?  Shouldn't the minimum be -2?  Your problem statement and your example are contradictory.

Comment: @rayryeng- THats the whole point. if you could imagine it like a curve, i want to find the dip in curve that occurs before the peak. I want to find the index of this. In above example 14. Any ideas ?

Comment: It is difficult to imagine it like a curve. Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with graphs, pictures etc so that we can make sense of your question. It is for a reason the help section advises the askers to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have edited the post and added link to the plot. Sorry if i am not astill able to convey things concisely.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but I can suggest a way to avoid the `while` loop. Instead try `Bdiff = diff(B(i,1:o(i))); ind = find(Bdiff>0,1,'last')` to get the desired index `ind`.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski Diff apparently find difference between each matlab data. But i need the difference between the Global max and the minima before it.
THe problem is locating this minima in the data.

Comment: @vittalrao Yes, that's what the `find` statement is for.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski tried this with a dummy array, seems to give a random index that doesnt make any sense.